# Change detail items using UWP master-detail

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm learning and creating a master-detail project using "Windows Template Studio".

Now I want to change the details, and want the changes shown in the master.
Like below
[image]

But I don't known how?
I have upload the sample code to GitHub.
https://github.com/hupo376787/App2

Can anyone change the sample code, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to automatically update the *company* field on the list when the `Company` property gets changed, you need to make the following changes -

1. You need to add `Mode=OneWay` to your binding in *MasterDetailPage*
   since the default mode in `x:Bind` is `OneTime`, which means once
   the value is set, it will never be updated.

   ```
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
              Text="{x:Bind Company, Mode=OneWay}"
              Style="{StaticResource ListSubTitleStyle}" />
   ```
2. Your `Order` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`
   otherwise the change will never make to the UI.

   ```
   public class Order: INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       private string _company;

       public string Company
       {
           get => _company;
           set
           {
               if (_company == value) return;

               _company = value;
               OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
       protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
       {
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
   }
   ```
3. In your `TextBox`, you will need
   `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in the binding 'cause you want
   to trigger the update by every key down. Unfortunately this is not
   supported in `x:Bind` so you will have to change back to use the
   traditional `Binding`. Note once you have changed it, you will also
   need to give your `UserControl` a name, say `Self`, so you can use
   `ElementName` to locate the same binding expression (i.e.
   MasterMenuItem.Company).

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="App2.Views.MasterDetailDetailControl"
                ...
                x:Name="Self">

   <TextBox Text="{Binding MasterMenuItem.Company, ElementName=Self, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
   ```

   />

Now run your app and it should work just fine. :)

Comment: Thanks, Justin. I forgot the 1st step...haha

Answer (score 0):

The `Order` item that is bound to the Master view needs to notify the view of the property change, so should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged)